# nvidia-settings is not showing most options

Tags: xorg, tearing, nvidia-settings

nvidia-settings is only showing the 'Application Profiles' and 'Configure Nvidia Settings' menus. I've tried running it as root, i've tried reinstalling the drivers, i've tried everything I can think of and it refuses to let me use the rest of the program. All I want to do is turn on VSync.

UPDATE: I yet to find a way to make my manually-created xorg.conf file stay after a reboot (it just vanishes)

EDIT: Using UbuntuGNOME